# What's the place of this code about urls in webview?

Tags: android, url, browser, webview

I want to add this code to my java file:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
           view.getContext().startActivity(
               new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }
}
```

But I don't know where. This is my java file:
    package sherdle.donald.duck.app;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    public class WebPageLoader extends Activity
    {
    WebView webview;

```
final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
    {
        activity.setTitle("Loading...");
        activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

        if(progress == 100)
            activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }
 });

 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
   });



 webview.loadUrl("http://www.sherdle.com/apphosting/dd");
 }

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed (){
    if(webview.canGoBack()) webview.goBack();
    else super.onBackPressed();
 }
 }
```

I'm new to android and  I need much help for everything I do. Thanks for your help.

I've got already this now:
    package sherdle.donald.duck.app;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    public class WebPageLoader extends Activity
    {
    WebView webview;

```
final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

 webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
    {
        activity.setTitle("Loading...");
        activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

        if(progress == 100)
            activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }
 });



 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
 });

 webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
           view.getContext().startActivity(
               new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }

  webview.loadUrl("http://www.sherdle.com/apphosting/dd");
  }



 @Override
 public void onBackPressed (){
    if(webview.canGoBack()) webview.goBack();
    else super.onBackPressed();
 }
 }
```

But I get this error on my LoadUrl line:
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
     Expression
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in this way

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

 webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
    {
        activity.setTitle("Loading...");
        activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

        if(progress == 100)
            activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }
 });



 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
 });

 webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
           view.getContext().startActivity(
               new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }


  });

webview.loadUrl("http://www.sherdle.com/apphosting/dd");


 }

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed (){
    if(webview.canGoBack()) webview.goBack();
    else super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

Comment: this whould look like this `public class yourActivity extends Activity { above code }`

Comment: I stil get errors: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method startActivity(Intent) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments 
  (Intent)
 - Line breakpoint:WebPageLoader [line: 54] - shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, String)  and also: Multiple markers at this line
 - Intent cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
 - Uri cannot be resolved
 - Intent cannot be resolved to a 
  type

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thanks! I've got one question left: If i want to add more then one url starts with... how?

Comment: What do you mean by more then one URL?Can you explain it more..and it is better to post it as a separate question. and Accept a Answer so that this question will be done..

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have webview in your layout. Also make sure you have the following line in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then you add that in your onCreate. It may not be the best, but it'll suffice.

Comment: Yes I've got internet connection and my webview works allready. But where in my OneCreate exactly? Can you please copy the code to my java file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but how can you not understand where to insert that piece of code if you have exactly that same method already overridden? Look where it says:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

If you want to change the behaviour above, simply replace these two lines specified by that in the first code snippet.

I've got a feeling you don't really understand [anonynous inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html), as you also try to set a `WebChromeClient` twice - that doesn't really make sense. I suggest you do some reading on the matter.

Also, the [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method is defined by a `WebViewClient`, not a `WebChromeClient`. That's a case of simply consulting the documentation.